# produce a stacked barplot from frequencies

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a data frame like this:

```
head(mydata)
id GeoBefore GeoAfter
1          A        A
2          B        B
3          A        B
4          B        A
5          A        A
6          B        B
```

I'd like to plot a stacked bar chart with two columns, GerBefore and GeoAfter, and I'd like to show how many A, B, etc... there are in each bar

I am trying to do:

```
gb <- cbind(mydata$GeoBefore, "2014")
ga <- cbind(mydata$GeoAfter, "2015")
geo <- as.data.frame(rbind(gb,ga))
colnames(geo) <- c("value", "period")
head(geo)
barplot(geo,
   legend.text=geo$period,
   args.legend=list(bty="n",horiz=TRUE),
   col=brewer.pal(5,"Set1"),border="white",
   main="Title")
```

but get:

```
Error in barplot.default(geo, legend.text = geo$period, args.legend = list(bty = "n",  : 
'height' must be a vector or matrix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
ans <- cbind(table(mydata$GeoBefore),table(mydata$GeoAfter))

colnames(ans) <- c("GeoBefore","GeoAfter")

barplot(ans,legend.text = rownames(ans))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

untested

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(geo, aes(x = period, fill = value)) +
  geom_histogram()
```